# <apex:outputText Not considering css being applied?

Tags: visualforce, css

i have a visualforce page where i need to display some rich text fields, and i found some CSS that makes the font resize based on the display widht of the device.
This works perfectly with a normal text, but once i use the tag <apex:outputText this doesn't work anymore.
Do you guys know how to apply it to apex:outputtext?

For me it would be ok to have another tag that lets me show rich text and apply CSS to it, not necessarily apex:outputtext, but it seems to be the only one who works with rich text fields.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" >
        <apex:slds /> 
 <style>
font-size: calc(3vw + 3vh);

</style>
<div class="resizeme">
  <svg
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    viewBox="0 0 500 75"
    preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid meet"
    style="background-color:green"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  >
         <text
          x="0"
          y="75"
          font-size="16"
          fill="black"
        ><apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!Account.Text__c}"  ></apex:outputText></text>
      </svg>
    
</div>

</apex:page>
```

Edit : As you see here on the iPad version the text with the red border is as i want, taking the whole widht and using the CSS.
The text below instead is using the apexoutput tag and it's resizing and wrapping between the 2 pictures, the second one is the phone view.
[image]
[image]

Comment: one way to debug this is to look at the generated HTML for each experiment to give you a clue.

Comment: Ok i uploaded now 2 pictures to explain it better.

Comment: Post the HTML markup please

Comment: I'm miscommunicating somehow -- generated HTML, not the VF markup for both the working and not working use cases; you'll need to use browser developer tools to get the markup.

Comment: Ok which html exactly? because the ones i found in the developer tool are super long.

Comment: Just the html and css associated with the field in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Made it work in the end by using the tag : apex:outputField
But this works only if you want to print a field value, not a string.